# How to query api based on user form input

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post, get

I have a node app in which I am calling the google places api and sending that data to the frontend. In the front end I have a basic form that posts to my node server. I want to return data from api calls based on the users form input.

I'm able to post the form to the server and I see the data in the request object however I am having trouble figuring out how can I use this data to correctly query the api based on the form inputs ?

The form

```
 <form method="post" class="form" action="http://localhost:3005/dyno">
<fieldset class="form-fieldset ui-input __first">
  <input type="text" name="interests" id="username" tabindex="0" />
  <label for="intrests">
    <span data-text="Interests">Intrests</span>
  </label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="form-fieldset ui-input __second">
  <input type="text" name="location" id="email" tabindex="0" />
  <label for="location">
    <span data-text="Location">Location</span>
  </label>
</fieldset>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

The server side code that logs the data I need

```
app.post('/dyno', function(request, response){

console.log(request.body.interests)
console.log(request.body.gender)

response.end()

});
```

The API call

```
 _EXTERNAL_URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.663918,-73.8820044&radius=2500&type=gyms&keyword=fitness&key=${KEY}`;

app.get('/ruckus',(req, res) => {
request(_EXTERNAL_URL, function (error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
console.log(body) 
res.send(body) 
}
});
})
```

How can I return data based on the radius,type and keyword parameters based on form data inputted by a user ?

Comment: you just form the _EXTERNAL_URL  with whatever data that you got from the submitted form. Something like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.663918,-73.8820044&radius=${req.body.radius}&type=${req.body.type}&keyword=${req.body.keyword}&key=${KEY}`;

Comment: That is not going to work, the request data is in a different endpoint

Comment: you can't merge these 2 endpoints ?

Comment: How will you hit these endpoints?

Comment: One calls the external api and the other received post data from a form, I don't see how you could combine the two.

Comment: You want to call the external API when the form is submitted right?

Comment: Yes I do, however I'm not sure how

Comment: kindly find the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side

- Prevent the form submit default.
- Form the body or query with the form inputs.
- Make fetch request to "http://localhost:3005/dyno"
- Render the received response from that request.

Server-side

- You create an endpoint named '/dyno'
- Get the body/query params from the request
- Form the URL to make request to Google Places API
- Make the request and return the response to client

Comment: That merges them however leave the external api unable to be called with a fetch in the frontend right ?

Comment: @RomaneGreen you can directly make request to the external API using fetch from Front-end

Comment: @RomaneGreen you can resolve those variables in the external_URL directly from the values of the form input controls.

Comment: The Google places API I am using is sever side only

Comment: @RomaneGreen You want to call the Google places API only when the form is submitted right?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do

Comment: @RomaneGreen then why would you have to call the external API with a fetch?

Comment: After the user submits the form , I would then like to call the api based on the users input and then show that data in the front end.

Comment: @RomaneGreen Then you prevent the default functionality of submit & make the fetch request there and get the response & render

Comment: That was my first try ,T hat does not work , the Google places API says it can only be fetched/ requested server side.

Comment: @RomaneGreen you make the fetch request to http://localhost:3005/dyno.

Comment: @RomaneGreen In the dyno endpoint you make request to Google places & return the response

Comment: That sounds like it'll work but doesn't localhost:3005/Dyno  render nothing because it has no GET. Request attached ?